# javascript tag in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

Like the title says I'm trying to add a javascript tag into a innerHTML.
I have a combobox and depending on which value is selected it should load a script into a div
the script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_cashieProductID=292016;
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + 
('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 
"somelink.js' 
type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

when I put this into my script it shows all kind of text on my page that is part of the combobox script. So I hope someone can help me how to insert this code into my script so it will show the content that gets loaded with the code given above.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console when you are inserting this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<select id="product" onchange="validate()">

function validate()
{
     pName = document.getElementById('product');
     var value = pName.options[pName.selectedIndex].value;
     if(value == "4OFC")
     loadJs(detail,"myjsSrc");
     else if(/*some conditon*/)
     {
         // use this ladder to change the script address based on value of select box
     }
     else{
     }
}
   function loadJs(targetDiv,source)
    {
       var ele = document.getElementById(targetDiv);
       if(ele)
       {
          var scr = document.createElement('script');
          scr.type = 'text/javascript';
          scr.src = source;
          ele.appendChild(scr);

       }
    }
```

Comment: could you give me an example on how to work with this if I this is my combobox onchange code:
if($('#product').val()=="4OFC")
   {
   }

and the name of the div id that should held the script I'm trying to load is "detail"

Comment: could you check your fb inbox please

Comment: @user2941187 Why ? i checked there is nothing

Comment: I sent you a message it should be in the folder others instead of in the folder inbox

Comment: @user2941187 Check your inbox too on FB

Answer (score 0):

Just try the actual string in document.write, like this:

```
document.write("<script src='" + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + "somelink.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
```

Comment: it took away the error I was having that it showed text on my html page that is inside my javascript function. but it doesn't load the script that should be loaded

Comment: Take a look on this article: http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2008/06/01/dynamically-including-javascript-and-css-files/